# Does A Function's Workspace Duplicate A Variable Input?

Tags: matlab, function, workspace

I have defined in the base Workspace a variable

`a = ones(10);`

And I would like to create function that inputs a vector `vec1` and gives back `vec2`:

```
function vec2 = myfun(vec1)

Operations with vec1

end
```

Lets make

```
b = myfun(a);
```

In the Workspace of `myfun` we will have a variable called `vec1` which has the same values as `a` but it is not in the base Workspace.

When being in Debugging Mode and using

```
dbup;
```

I can see two different variables `a` and `vec1` in base and myfun Workspaces respectively.

Is `myfun` duplicating the variable a in two different Workspaces (and therefore using more memory)?

If this is not the case, how does it work? Is it a pointer assigning two different names to the same information?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MATLAB uses a system commonly called "copy-on-write" to avoid making a copy of the input argument inside the function workspace until or unless you modify the input argument. If you do not modify the input argument, MATLAB will avoid making a copy. For instance, in this code:

```
function y = functionOfLargeMatrix(x) 
     y = x(1);
```

MATLAB will not make a copy of the input in the workspace of `functionOfLargeMatrix`, as `x` is not being changed in that function. If on the other hand, you called this function:

```
function y = functionOfLargeMatrix2(x) 
      x(2) = 2;  
      y = x(1);
```

then `x` is being modified inside the workspace of `functionOfLargeMatrix2`, and so a copy must be made.

Comment: No worries. This is a great, simple, accurate answer. Good job